# Reject Open Graph Action Review with explicitly shared

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

we have submitted for approval three actions (2 custom and 1 common, watch) on Facebook Open Graph, this is the text that we have write in the review instruction:

```
The action Add and Watch are published only if user has activated the automatic 
sharing inside his profile settings. Those actions use explicitly sharing only 
and if only if the corresponded switch is on.

In order to use Share action, user have to touch the rounded Facebook button 
at the bottom of the episode page or the series page, then he can write a comment 
and only by touching send the action is published. The control is inside user's
hands, and it is obvious that the sharing is explicit.
```

we have also insert this image along with other images, that show that a user have to enable explicitly the options to make a explicitly share:

[image]

and one action need that the user touch a sharing button to be shared.

But Facebook have reject all the action, and have answered this:

[image]

[image]

we doesn't know how make it, and we need that this actions are explicitly because the user ask it to us. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the explicit option in your settings that's causing Facebook to reject your story. Explicit shares have to be explicitly shared by the user each time (hence the name), so by having an automatic explicit share option that shares the story without the user choosing to share it each time, you're breaking the rules. That's a really complicated sentence... Basically, the user has to choose to share a post every single time for it to be explicit. If it posts automatically without any interaction from the user, then it's implicit.

So your "share" instructions, with the user hitting a share button, is the correct usage. Add and Watch are not.

Comment: GetGlue make the same explicitly sharing but they doesn't ask every time to the user, how they do it?

Comment: Are you sure they're posting with the explicit flag enabled? They may also have a different workflow where users 'check in' to each show they're sharing to Facebook instead of it being implicit

Comment: yes i'm sure, and this error instead: "Web I am unable to test this submission because the link you have provided is intended for a different platform. Please only submit the relevant platforms for review and provide proper usage instruction for each platform." what they mean?